# Como é que o compilador do Java funciona?

Tags: java, compilação

Porque é que o compilador do `Java` não consegue adivinhar qual o tipo do objeto que vai ser devolvido na linha que vai provocar erro de compilação neste programa?

```
import java.util.*;

class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //The following code snippet without generics requires casting
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("hello");
        System.out.println(list.get(0));

        //String s = (String) list.get(0);
        String s = list.get(0);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No Java 1.4, não havia o recurso de [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Este recurso foi implementado a partir do java 1.5 (que oficialmente passou a ser chamado de Java 5).

Embora você não esteja percebendo, o compilador está fazendo da seguinte maneira:

1. Instancie uma ArrayList de **Object** e atribua a variável *list*.
2. Adicione uma String na *list*

Neste momento, o cast não é preciso porquê String é uma instancia de **Object** também (Toda classe que não extenda outra classe declarativamente atravez da palavra extends, automaticamente irá extender **Object**])

3. Pegue o Object da *list* que esteja na posição 0 dela e mande imprimir.

Embora você esteja imaginando que esteja chamando System.out.println(String), na verdade, está chamando System.out.println(Object), que internamente irá fazer System.out.println(Object.toString())

4. Aqui, você está tentando pegar um objeto da *list* de **Object** e tentando atribuir a uma **String** diretamente.

Não pode, pois embora toda **String** seja um **Object**, nem sempre todo **Object** será uma **String**. Para que você consiga fazer esta atribuição, você precisará falar para o compilador que assume o risco, fazendo um [cast](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-object-typecasting/):

```
String s = (String) list.get(0); // eu assumo o risco
```

Se quiser fazer declarativamente uma Lista de String, a partir do Java 5, você pode usar genérics para resolver seu problema ([não esquecer de olhar o javadoc da classe List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html)):

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("hello");
String hello = strings.get(0); // ok, strings é uma List<String>.
```

No java 5, se você tentar declarar um List sem atribuir um parâmetro genérico, ele irá assumir que é um List para manter compatibilidade com o Java 1.4.

**Links uteis**:

[Hierarquia da classe Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)